# How to get a list of all available packet names in Node.js JavaScript Client for MySQL?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Where may I read a list of all available packets to select which ones I need for a `debug` array ([here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options))?

> `debug`: Prints protocol details to stdout. Can be true/false ***or an array of packet type names*** that should be printed. (Default: false)

They mentioned the option in docs but forgot to supply any link or a list of available packet names.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. A name of a file references a packet name (I hope):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/tree/master/lib/protocol/packets

This is how it may be implemented in an app:

```
module.exports = {
    'development': {
        host: 'your-db-host.com',
        port: 3306,
        database: 'your-db-name',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'userpassword',
        connectionLimit: 10,

        // or an array of packet type names that should be printed.
        debug: ['ComQueryPacket', 'OkPacket', 'ComQueryPacket', 'ResultSetHeaderPacket', 'ErrorPacket'],
    },
}
```